# JPA Hibernate: How to query for Child Entities of the same Type as the Parent across multiple levels

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I have a business requirement, I need to implement a tree structure, which is modeled as follows:

```
Folder 1 (Type Folder.class)
    -- Folder 1.1 (Type Folder.class)
       -- Folder 1.1.1 (Type Folder.class)

            -- Item 1A (Type Item.class)
            -- Item 1B (Type Item.class)

       -- Folder 1.1.2 (Type Folder.class)

            -- Item 2A (Type Item.class)
            -- Item 2B (Type Item.class)
```

I have two entities, `Folder.java` and `Item.java` as follows

`Folder.java`

```
@Entity
public class Folder{
    @Id
    private Long id;
    private String name;

    //...other fields...//

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="PARENT_FOLDER_ID")
    private Folder parentFolder;



    //... Getters and Setters...//
}
```

and `Item.java`

```
@Entity
public class Item{
    @Id
    private Long id;
    private String name;

    //...other fields...//

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="PARENT_FOLDER_ID")
    private Folder parentFolder;



    //... Getters and Setters...//
}
```

I'm able to create `Item` and `Folder` objects as per the hierarchy shown above, and am able to persist them to the database. So, all CRUD operations are working fine.

My requirement now is such that, I must be able to get a `List<Item>` when given a `Folder` as input, according to the below table:

**Scenario 1:** When the input is `Folder 1.1.1` the output should be `Item 1A`, `Item 1B`.

**Scenario 2:** When the input is `Folder 1.1`,  the output should be `Item 1A`, `Item 1B`, `Item 2A`, `Item 2B`

**Scenario 2:** When the input is `Folder 1`,  the output should be `Item 1A`, `Item 1B`, `Item 2A`, `Item 2B`

I have been able to accomplish **Scenario 1** using JPA hiberante's `Query by example` (set `item.setParentFolder()`) to set the parent folder, and I get a list of all Items under that folder.

But how can I do this when the parent has no direct `Item`s, but their child folders have?

Thanks,
Sriram Sridharan

Comment: Sounds to me like you need a "nested" table hierarchy in your database, so you would need a table that has a FK costraint on itself, and that COULD have a FK with an external table "Item".

Comment: Could you elaborate on your answer please? As the Folders table has an FK constraint on itself and the Items table has an FK constraint with the Folder Table.

Comment: Something like this https://pastebin.com/raijrD8Y

Comment: You would basically an entity that references itself as a `@ManyToOne` relation, and it would also have a `@OneToMany` to itself, so you would have two additional fields:
        @ManyToOne
        @JoinColumn(name="ID")
        private Folder parent;

        @OneToMany(mappedBy="parent")
        private List<Folder> children;

Comment: Yes, I have that in place now, but how do I achieve the scenarios listed above? My question is how would I query for Items across Folder levels?